# Configuring DataSource and JdbcTemplate in a Standalone Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, datasource, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am writing a **standalone Spring Boot app** that is going to fetch data from SQLServer and insert into MySQL database.

I think I structured the app properly and believe I am on the right track. However, I am unable to figure out:

1. How to setup/configure DataSource and JdbcTemplate.
2. Then how to setup **two different** DataSource and JdbcTemplate; one for SQLServer and one for MySQL.

[Here](https://github.com/gauz09/SpringBoodStandaloneTest) is my Git repo link for you to look at the my project structure and initial code.

Can somebody please help me on how should go about setting up **DataSource** and **JdbcTemplate**?

Thanks.

Comment: please google it first, https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Comment: @clevertension - thanks for the reply! That answers my second question. You are right, I could have searched for it. However, the main reason for me to create this post on SO was to get an answer for the first question. And since I was asking it, I thought of putting the second one too. I am sorry if that's not the right way. Definitely didn't mean to waste anybody's time. And I did do lots and lots of search before creating this post. I have upvoted your comment for giving the answer to second question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know how to give 2 set of properties for each db in property files like this.

```
# Oracle DB - "foo"
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db-server-foo:1521/FOO
spring.datasource.hikari.username=fooadmin
spring.datasource.hikari.password=foo123
spring.datasource.hikari.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
# Ignite DB - "bar"
bar.datasource.hikari.url=jdbc:postgresql://db-server-bar:5432/bar
bar.datasource.hikari.username=baradmin
bar.datasource.hikari.password=bar123
bar.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

then configure datasource and jdbc template like this.

```
 /**
 * Auto-configured DataSource
 */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

/**
 * New Data source declared to connect to the Ignite in-memory Cache database.
 *
 * @return instance of DriverManagerDataSource
 */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource.hikari")
@Bean
public DataSource igniteDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

/**
 * Initialize the jdbc template to connect to ignite datasource.
 *
 * @return instance of JdbcTemplate to connect ot <code>igniteDataSource()</code>
 */
@Bean
@Primary
public JdbcTemplate igniteTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(igniteDataSource());
}

/**
 * Initialize the jdbc template to connect to the Oracle database.
 *
 * @return instance of JdbcTemplate to connect ot <code>dataSource()</code>
 */
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate dbjdbcTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}
```